# Errors when trying to use localStorage to save and load arrays with objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, canvas

I'm currently working on a game as my "final project" in my beginner programming class. Therefore, a central part is to be able to save game data. In the game, there are 4 arrays with 9 places each, representing the inventory in game. The inventory prints the image of the item in the inventory slot that the item is in. One is for the item object:

> this.inventory = {1: num[1], 2: num[30], 3: num[33], 4: num[9], 5: "empty", 6: "empty", 7: "empty", 8: "empty", 9: "empty"};

each item(ex num[1]) has an .image property, and a .data property.
The next array is used to define the amount of that item:

> this.inventoryStack = {1: 1, 2: 7, 3: 99, 4: 5500, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0};

Then there's one for the image, followed by one for the data(data is stored in separate array):

> this.images = {1: num[1].image, 2: num[30].image, 3: num[33].image, 4: num[9].image, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0};
>
> this.data = {1: rods[0], 2: num[30].data, 3: num[33].data, 4: num[9].data, 5: 0 , 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0};

[The result of these these arrays will look like this in the game:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5x4B.png)

I'm using the localStorage method as shown below to first save the data, and then restore with separate keyboard presses:

```
     this.save = function() {

            if(keyState[77]) {

            localStorage.setItem("inventorySave", JSON.stringify(this.inventory));
            localStorage.setItem("stackSave", JSON.stringify(this.inventoryStack));
            localStorage.setItem("imageSave", JSON.stringify(this.images));
            localStorage.setItem("dataSave", JSON.stringify(this.data));

        }
    }

    this.restore = function() {


            if(keyState[78] && this.restorer == true) {
            this.restorer = false;
            }
            if(this.restorer == false && this.restoreTick < 2) this.restoreTick++;
            if(this.restoreTick == 1) for(var i in this.inventoryStack) this.inventoryStack[i] = 0;
            if(this.restoreTick == 2) {
                this.parser1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("inventorySave")); 
                this.parser2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("stackSave"));
                this.parser3 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("imageSave"));
                this.parser4 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dataSave"));
                for(var i in this.parser1) {
                    if(this.parser1[i] != "empty") {

                    this.inventory[i] = this.parser1[i];
                    this.inventoryStack[i] = this.parser2[i];
                    this.images[i] = this.parser3[i];
                    this.data[i] = this.parser4[i];  
                    }
                }
                    if(!keyState[78]) {
                    this.restoreTick = 0;
                    this.restorer = true;
                    }
            }

    }
```

However, when I try to save and then restore, I get this error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'"

I am wondering, what could be the error here? This is my first question here, so sorry for any bad formulations or descriptions! I have watched other question on the topic, but they could not help me :(

Comment: simple trick. localStorage and sessionStorage, both can't save objects or array, only strings. make JSON.stringify(object) before adding and JSON.parse on reading

Comment: @TypedSource ...did you read the question? OP is doing exactly that.

Comment: oops, sorry, not seen ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't save HTMLImageElements into localStorage and expect an HTMLImageElement back out, which I'm assuming `this.images` corresponds to.

Instead, you'll need to save just the data you want, and re-instantiate the image element.

Assuming `this.images` is an object of image elements for values you can copy them to a new object to serialize to save just a list of sources and then re-map to a list of NEW HTMLImageElements when you restore. There's a few ways to iterate over objects, but here's the oldest and most compatible way:

```
this.save = function() {
  // Save a list of srcs from each Image element in this.images
  var imageSrcs = {};
  for (var key in this.images) {
    if (this.images.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      imageSrcs[key] = this.images[key].src;
    }
  }
  localStorage.setItem("imageSrcsSave", JSON.stringify(imageSrcs));
}

this.restore = function() {
  // Restore the stored sources and instantiate NEW image elements
  // into this.images.
  var imageSrcs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("imageSrcsSave"));
  this.images = {};
  for (var key in imageSrcs) {
    if (imageSrcs.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this.images[key] = new Image();
      this.images[key].src = imageSrcs[key];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: absolutely correct. seen it a few seconds before your answer was posted

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! When I try to run the save function, I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: this.images.map is not a function. What's the problem now?

Comment: @ErikLundin Ooops. Didn't realize `this.images` is not an Array (`map` is only on Array, not Object). I've updated the answer to iterate over an Object correctly.

Comment: Great answer , Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, I realised that was the problem as well, even though I had no idea on how to fix it... thanks once again!